# What's the best way to store/query `last_read` in Mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB (via Mongoose/Node), and I'm trying to figure out the best way to store and query for a `last_read` Date field. I have a collection of Posts, and each time a visitor views one of them, I want to store the timestamp.

Additionally, I'd like to query for any Posts that have been updated since the current user's `last_read` timestamp.

This seems pretty standard, but I couldn't find much.

To me, the simplest approach seems like storing a hash on the Post, keyed by visitor ID with the value being a Date. The Mongoose schema would look something like:

```
{
  title: String,
  created: Date,
  modified: Date,
  last_read: {} // Mixed
}
```

Then upon loading a Post page, I'm running:

```
var update = {};
update.last_read[req.user.id] = new Date();
Posts.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, update, cb);
```

which works, and now my Post doc looks like:

```
{
  title: 'My new post',
  created: 2015-04-01 06:25:53.094Z,
  modified: 2015-04-02 07:29:01.094Z
  last_read: {
    123userID456: 2015-04-01 06:25:53.094Z
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to query for Posts that have been modified more recently that the current user's `last_read` time. Do I need to use the aggregation pipeline?

I'm also second-guessing this storage approach altogether. At first it seems like the simplest option, but something about using the user ID as object keys feels wrong.

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: Is it important for you who last read the post?

Comment: Hi Edgar, thanks. Yes it is important. I need to show a count per user of how many "unread" Posts they have. ("unread" meaning Posts they've never read and/or Posts that have been updated since the last time they read them).

Comment: You can create new collection, for instance read_posts, and when user read post insert (or update timestamp if exist) the object like {userID, postID, timestamp}.

Comment: As a side note: using semantic values as keys leads to problems sooner or later more often than not. So your `last_read` should hold an array of subdocs like `{userId:"123userId456",date:2015-04-01T06:25:53.094Z}`. Which actually solves your problem, as you simply push a new document containing the respective values to that array on read.

Comment: @Edgar: Thanks. Please see my comment on Mustafa's answer. I'm not sure a separate collection is appropriate..?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: Thanks, you've suggested a similar approach to Mustafa's answer below. I commented there, but to reiterate, how would I handle updating timestamps?

Comment: @SnidelyWhiplash: Erm, create a new subdoc with the timestamp field set to `Date.now()`?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: But then I'd end up with multiple entries per-user. What I need is an upsert $addToSet, ultimately. Doesn't look like there's an atomic way to do that though, from what I've read.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you need the type Mixed for.

Without altering your aproach of saving data, you should change the Schema to something like this:

```js
{
  title: String,
  created: Date,
  modified: Date,
  last_read: [{
    _id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'user'
    },
    at: Date
  }]
}
```

Using this Schema, you can edit the list of users who read the post like this:

```js
// Add
post.last_read.push({
  _id: user.id,
  at: new Date()
});

// Find
var last_read = post.last_read.id(user.id);

// Edit
last_read.at = new Date();

// Save
post.save(callback);
```

For more information on Sub Documents, please check [Mongoose Documentation on topic](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html).

But I suggest using a separate collection for this use case. Because you are going to have too many posts to read for a particular user and too many users to read for a particular post. Big documents cause performance problems for MongoDB, more than querying or editing an extra collection.

```js
{
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
  },
  post: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'post'
  },
  last_read: Date
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not concerned about the doc size tbh. Each Post will only be accessible to a limited number of users (they need to be invited), and probably not all of them will actually view it. Plus, a separate collection feels too relational for Mongo, no? I think it makes sense to store this all on the Post itself. But as to your first example, how would I update an existing entry? Every time a user views the Post, I need to INSERT a new object to that array if one doesn't exist. If they've already viewed it though I need to UPDATE that array entry specifically with the new timestamp. Thanks.